# WSO2 API Manager, Websocket API how to disable the security

Tags: websocket, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 and I want to know if there is any configuration in the Websocket API that we can change to disable the security or if we can change the default security to the api key. By default it cames with the OAuth.

For the Rest API it has a property x-wso2-disable-security that we can insert in the OpenAPI definition to remove the security, like mentioned in this link (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/choreo-connect/security/api-authentication/disabling-security/#by-updating-the-openapi-definition), but I didn't found any similar approach to do this in the Websocket.

If this is not possible to achieve, is it somehow possible to change the Authorization header name that WSO2 use to a custom name? For example: The WSO2 needs a "Authorization: Bearer [access_token]", can I change to "AuthorizationWSO2: Bearer [access_token]"?

Already tried to add the x-wso2-disable-security in the AsyncAPI Definition, without success. I was expecting that with the x-wso2-disable-security, all the websockets APIs were accessed without security

Comment: Are you trying this with Choreo Connect Gateway or APIM default gateway?

Comment: I'm using APIM default gateway

Answer (score 0):

x-wso2-disable-security and other vendor extensions are only supported for OpenAPI definitions. For web socket APIs, the definition is Async API definition and it does not have this support yet.

In the latest versions, these features are not available for web socket APIs. One option is to write a custom handler and replace the existing authentication handlers so that the token validations won't take place.

Also you can engage another handler so that it reads the header AuthorizationWSO2 and send it as a separate header called Authorization to the other handler chain which helps to do the proper validation.

Please refer the guide for writing a custom handler - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler

Comment: Thanks for the response Pubci. I also found this implementation here using message mediation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/) that is basically what I need for my solution, but I have 2 questions. 1. I didn't found this same implementation for the version 4.1.0, the mediation was removed from this version? 2. Is this possible to implement mediation in Websocket?

Comment: Message mediation is only support for the REST APIs and it is not there for websocket APIs.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the confirmation! I will try the custom handler for the Websocket APIs

Comment: @Pubci: That link seems to refer to the REST flows.  The class inherits `AbstractHandler`  The Web Socket handlers seem to inherit different classes and even different interfaces.  Any documentation specifically for web sockets?